# Sending id param to json with Rails, ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this ajax call that is activating an action in the controller. My problem is that the action does not recieve the params[:id] that the other methods in that controller have. I'm guessing it is because it gets the params from the url. But how do I send the current page id with the ajax ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/test",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Ajax error!")
    }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
 def test
   @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
   render :json =>   { :name => @user.username  }.to_json
 end
```

NB: The ajax is in a .js file not in the view. And it is activated when someone loads a page

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add your current page id as a hidden value, in the html. For example, in `example/current_view.html.erb`, add anywhere this line:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :current_id, params[:id] %>
```

Later, you can access that value in your ajax request and add it to the url, with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/test/" + $('#current_id').val(),
  type: "GET",
  ...
});
```

If you don't want to modify the current view, then you can parse the url (located in `window.location.href`) with javascript, and extract the id with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any `data` to the server. For detailed info. refer to jquery ajax documentation here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can either have a hidden variable on the page that stores the `id` or make it a data attribute.